# Django insert permission in migration

Tags: python, django, permissions, migration, database-migration

I need to populate auth_group_permission table in a migration. I've created a migration with this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.5 on 2017-12-05 10:07
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions

def add_group_permissions(apps, schema_editor):
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
        create_permissions(app_config, apps=apps, verbosity=0)

    #Workers
    group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='Workers')   
    can_add_worker_task = Permission.objects.get(codename='add_worker_task')
    group.permissions.add(can_add_worker_task)
    group.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('crowdsourcing', '0005_add_view_permission'),
        ('auth', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_group_permissions),
    ]
```

But when I execute "python manage.py migrate" commando I received this error: "django.contrib.auth.models.DoesNotExist: Permission matching query does not exist". I think the problem is that the "auth_permission" table is still empty. Can i solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solve with this code:

```
def add_group_permissions(apps, schema_editor):
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
       app_config.models_module = True
       create_permissions(app_config, apps=apps, verbosity=0)
       app_config.models_module = None
```